# Axios and the New york times API

Tags: reactjs, rest, api, react-native, axios

Am using axios to get data from the new york times search API to use on my react native app and for some reason i keep getting empty results. 
here is the code i used :

in nytimes.js file :

```
import axios from "axios";

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2",
  headers: {
    Authorization: "Bearer 'MY_API_KEY'",
  },
});
```

on my ResultDetails.js file :

```
const [results, setResutls] = useState([]);
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState("");
  const searchApi = async (searchTerm) => {
    // wait for a reponse to get back once it does with some data we asign that data to the reponse variable
    try {
      const reponse = await nytimes.get("/articlesearch", {
        params: {
          //limit: 50,
          q: searchTerm, // q is term
          //
        },
      });
      setResutls(reponse.data.docs); //docs
    } catch (err) {
      setErrorMessage("Something went wrong");
    }
  };
  // bad code
  //searchApi("pasta");
  useEffect(() => {
    searchApi("covid");
  }, []);
```

i use `<Text>{results.length}</Text>` to see if i got any results back.
when i console.log(err) in the catch block i get this :

```
Request failed with status code 404
- node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:3:19 in <global>
- node_modules\axios\lib\core\settle.js:14:6 in settle
- node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\xhr.js:57:8 in handleLoad
- node_modules\event-target-shim\dist\event-target-shim.js:818:39 in EventTarget.prototype.dispatchEvent
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:566:23 in setReadyState
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:388:25 in __didCompleteResponse
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\vendor\emitter\EventEmitter.js:190:12 in emit
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:436:47 in __callFunction
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:111:26 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:384:10 in __guard
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:110:17 in __guard$argument_0
* [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

Comment: Are you sure you get response.data.docs printed before `setResutls(reponse.data.docs);`

Comment: am not since the probelm is only axios realated not react related cause i tested it with an other api and diffrent parameters and it worked

Comment: In such a case please log the err in catch block to see what issue is happening and add it to your post

Comment: it gave me a status code of 404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using this code you can call the NYT's API using the data you sent in the comments area.
I'm listing all abstracts came from the API

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

import axios from 'axios';

export default function Home() {
  const [docs, setDocs] = useState([]);

  async function loadAPI() {
    const response = await axios.get(
      'https://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?q=election&api-key=h1TylVtDCbyqnZZWgBXfGhU0lXQr7Cw1'
    );

    setDocs(response.data.response.docs);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    loadAPI();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      {
        docs.map((article, index) => 
          <Text key={index}>
            {article.abstract}
          </Text>
        )
      }
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: i used the URL in my browser and its working but when i pass on axios i get a 401 status code

Comment: `export default axios.create({
  baseURL:
    "https://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?q=election&api-key=h1TylVtDCbyqnZZWgBXfGhU0lXQr7Cw1",
  headers: {
    
    Accept: "application/json",
  },
}); 
 ` 
and i used this for get const reponse = await nytimes.get("/")

Comment: Check my answer again... I have beem implemented it based on the information you just sent

Comment: I was happy to do it,